# html not linking css

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm having an issue with linking html and Css and have no idea why. I'm doing everything like the book and tutorials says. However, I'm not getting to do the external configuration of css.

This is the code(just a test):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "eng">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">

        <title>title</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">

        <link rel="stylesheets" type="text/css" href="/styles.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>test</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

and CSS:

```
body {
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}

h1 {
    color:#0000EE;
}
```

Maybe I miss something, because when I do internal css (within my html code with ) it goes ok and the web browser is able to read that. It seems like the html is not linked with css, but it's even on the same folder so the path shouldn't be the problem.

I'm using Linux and Aptana Studio.

I've searched a lot the last 2 hours and cannot find where the mistake is.

Comment: Do you have `styles.css` file next to the `html` file? and has css content?

Answer (score 11):

I invite you to read this article [Absolute and Relative Paths](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm)

Then we pass to your code:

`<link rel="stylesheets" type="text/css" href="/styles.css">`

Should be :

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">`

Your `styles.css` should be in the same folder as your html file.

To verify that you have an error , check **Console** of your browser,you will be noticed that your file doesn't exist(404 error).

An other way to make your css working is to integrate it inside your page without separation:

**Example:**

```
 <style type='text/css'>

    body {
        background-color:#CCCCCC;
   }

    h1 {
        color:#0000EE;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

If the other suggestions don't work, you can try re-saving the HTML and CSS sheets with "UTF-8" encoding and declare UTF-8 encoding in the HTML under the `<head>` with `<meta charset="utf-8>"`

Comment: Wish I could tell you lol, probably has to do with certain characters being 'translated' differently between UTF encodings.. if youre interested there are articles you should read: 

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/all-about-unicode-utf8-character-sets/

i cant find the one that i read way back but this should suffice.

I remember seeing this workaround in a tutorial video around the time that i posted my solution.. glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

The rel attribute should just have stylesheet in it, singular not plural as well

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem correct the correct directory structure solved my problem. This is a good visualiton on how to organize your directory structure.

http://rosebusch.net/jeff/miscellaneous/tree.html

That is, the `index.html` folder is on the same level as the CSS folder. If you want to put `index.html` in a HTML folder, to link to the CSS folder you would have to backout first by linking `href="../css/stylesheet.css"`. The `".."` will take you up a level.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `style.css` is in your root web directory since that is where you are calling it from

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the / in front of styles.css and make sure they are in the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Language was wrong? -->
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">

        <title>title</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
<!-- Check the path to the file - I made it relative to where the HTML is -->
<!-- Correct the rel attribute's value too -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>test</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just that? Won't you explain why it should help to add that dot?

Answer (score 1):

If all the above not working:

1- Make sure you have no inline/internal CSS > Delete all style code from the Html page (it ll prevent **external css** link)

Answer (score 1):

If your CSS file are in another **folder** then use

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="folder-name/styles.css">`

Answer (score 1):

I found out while Using Visual Studio Code and adding quotes that it was quoting automatically. So when I put in quotes and looked in the index.html of the index it was quoting the quotes (Bad News). Try link
`<href=FILENAME.css rel=stylesheet type=text/css />`

Hope this works! Also, if you want Multiple CSS files, organize them in a folder, if you do so in FILENAME put /FOLDERNAME/FILENAME.css
BUT make SURE it is under the main folder where your Index is!

Answer (score 1):

just try tasking off the / in front of the style.css

Answer (score 0):

Place your link in the head tag or body tag, it is best to put it in the head tag.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32493990)