# Why is my html file not linking to my CSS layout?

Tags: html, css

I am using XAMPP and MyPHPadmin to setup a survey with a database that I will be using for a project.

Now I am trying to link my css file to my html file so that the layout changes. I am trying to link this with:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/Versie1.1/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

My css file is located at: C:\xampp\htdocs\Versie1.1\default.css

I have tried a lot of different hrefs as in: "default.css", c path to the default.css, etc.

Any idea why my layout is not changing to the one in the css file? If I put the css code inside the `<head>` it does work.

Comment: Have you checked the developer tools for errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html not linking css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422974/html-not-linking-css) and [thousands of other similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=html+not+linking+css)

Comment: Are you getting a 404? 403?... what's the error exactly?

Comment: `href="Versie1.1/default.css"` instead of `href="/Versie1.1/default.css"`. The latter is absolute path and the other is relative path.

Comment: Sari, im not getting any error. The layout is just not applying to the page.

Comment: J...S, tried that version as well, not working :/

Comment: My console log gives me this:
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xammp/htdocs/Versie%201.1/default.css

Comment: Is the XAMPP root set to the same directory as what you're trying to access to serve your CSS file from? Not used XAMPP for a long time so apologies for not being able to help further.

Comment: Yes Tom the root is set to the same directory.

Comment: Something similar to this perhaps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20434624/not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-file

Answer (score 0):

it's seems, some path problem.
If your porject file path is "C:\xampp\htdocs" in this path you have one folder 'Versie1.1' and a html file index.html, then your **"href=Versie1.1/default.css"**

**file structure**

`Versie1.1
   default.css
index.html`

**file structure**

`Versie1.1
   default.css
html
   index.html`

In this case link will be **"href=../Versie1.1/default.css"**

I hope you understand. Thank you!